# If I publish my paper in non-ISI journal, Will it appear on PubMed and other electronic databases, to the public?

Tags: publications, research-process, citations, thesis

If I publish my paper in non-ISI journal, will it appear on PubMed and other electronic databases, to the public?

Comment: Why did you repeat your question?

Answer (score 1):

Check with the publisher - they are the ones who will know. In particular, look at the journal's website and see if they have any "abstracting" or "indexing" information.

For example, Elsevier's [Journal of Theoretical Biology](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/journal-of-theoretical-biology/0022-5193/abstracting-indexing) is not ISI-web of science indexed, or PubMed indexed, but is indexed by a variety of other databases.